# Jquery Active State Based on Body ID

Tags: jquery, css

First off what are some of the better methods to achieve a jquery active state? I want to give each body a unique ID and use that to determine the active state. Is that a good method?

How could I give each of my pages body tags a unique id and then use jquery to add an active state to a similar menu using .addClass?

```
 <body id="two">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="one.html">one</a></li>
      <li><a href="two.html">two</a></li>
      <li><a href="three.html">three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav> 
 </body>
```

could i give each li a class and whichever one matches the id has a class added to it? Looking for suggestions on best methods.

Comment: Giving the body tag an ID is redundant since each document can only have one body.

Comment: Rather than giving the body an ID, use said id in your server-side script to set active class on the appropriate navigation link. If you don't have a server-side language, set the active class on each nav menu manually rather than manually setting the ID to the body.

Comment: So you want me to write a bunch of php if statements to add my active state? That seems redundant also. Why not just use jquery? I cant add each class manually. I use one menu and include it in all of my pages.

Comment: Why not have if statements? you can do that inline, and the "active" navigiation menu item will be "active" immediately rather than flashing inactive then active when the DOM is ready. It can be done with javascript, but why do it with JS when it can be done with php far easier with no impact on the page?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to create a single page application. There are many frameworks which implement this pattern including:

- [EmberJS](http://emberjs.com/)
- [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)
- [BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org/)
- [Instant Click](http://instantclick.io/)

These frameworks are immensely useful when using trying to create a single page application, but if you wish to implement it yourself, you would go about this by storing a template in a hidden DOM element like a `<script>` tag and switching a part of the body  with it on click. If you would like to support deep linking, eaither store the sub path in the hash fragment in the url.

Answer (score -2):

```js
if ($('body').is('#two') ){
   $( "ul li:nth-child(2)" ).addClass('active');
}
```